# Divergence theorem: why is it $F_n \cdot dS$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I am learning the calculus 3 interpretation of Stokes' theorems while just dipping my toe in the water of differential forms. Since I have only limited knowledge of the real differential geometry involved, I'm having trouble putting things together.

Reading the treatment of Stokes' theorems in Buck's *Advanced Calculus*, I find the following lemma relating the 2-form to the normal:

$$\int_{\Sigma} f dy dz + g dz dx + hdx dy \\= \int_{D} f \frac{ \partial(y,z) }{ \partial(u,v) }du dv + g \frac{ \partial(z,x) }{ \partial(u,v) }du dv + h\frac{ \partial(x,y) }{ \partial(u,v) }du dv\\ = \int_D \vec{U} \cdot \mathbf{n}(u,v)\, dA$$

where $\vec{U} = (f,g,h)$ and $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a parameterized surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\sigma(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))$.

The referring to $dudv$ as "$dA$" is a little confusing to me. "$dA$" seems to be something that if we integrated it, we should end up with the surface area of $\Sigma$ (I would like to think of it like "parameterizing by arclength".) But if we integrate $dudv$, we end up with the area in the parameter space.

OK, so perhaps the $dA$ refers to the area of the parameter space. But then [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement) on Wikipedia I find the statement

$$\iiint _V (\nabla \cdot F) dV = \iint_{S} F \cdot n \,dS.$$

which I read as translating

$$\int_V (f_x + g_y + h_z) dx dy dz \\=\int_V d(f\, dy dz + g \,dz dx + h \,dx dy) + \int_{\partial V}f\, dy dz + g \,dz dx + h \,dx dy.$$

Surely this $dS$ here does not refer to any particular parameterization space...? Here $dS$ is something which, if we integrated it, would yield the surface area of $S$, right?

**Question 2:** What 2-form would we integrate if we want the surface area of a parameterized surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You don't think the $\dfrac{\partial(y,z)}{\partial(u,v)}$ etc. terms relate parameter-space area to surface area?

Comment: I think that's right, but then I am confused because of the statement in Wikipedia, where $F \cdot n \,dS$ appears without any reference to a parameterization. Here $dS$ is something that if we integrated it we would get the surface area of $S$, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a line integral, you are not obtaining the arc length. You are integrating a 1-form along the line. That is, this:
$$
\int_L A\cdot dl = \int_L\left( A_x\,dx + A_ydy + A_z\,dz \right)  = \int_L \left( A_x\frac{dx}{dt}+A_y\frac{dy}{dt}+A_z\frac{dz}{dt}\right)\,dt
$$

is something different from this:
$$
\int_L |dl| = \int_L \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}=\int_L \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt.
$$

Just as well, there is a difference between integrating something (a 2-form) *over* a surface, and integrating the modulus of the area to obtain its absolute magnitude.

The first is:
$$
\int_S U\cdot n\,dS,
$$

which is exactly what you wrote, the second would be:
$$
\int_S \bigg| \frac{\partial \vec x}{\partial u}\wedge \frac{\partial \vec x}{\partial v}\bigg| \,du\,dv.
$$

The terms $dS$ could refer to both, and it is confusing, but they are different quantities.

In the first case, the *vector* $\vec n\,dS$ is the quantity:
$$
\frac{\partial \vec x}{\partial u}\wedge \frac{\partial \vec x}{\partial v}\,du\,dv;
$$

in the second case, the *scalar* $dS$ is the modulus of the vector above.
The situation is pretty much the same with $dl$ and $|dl|$ in the line case.

Comment: Is $dS= du dv$ here? Because what confused me is that in the text, the characterization of $f\,dydz + g\, dzdx + h \, dx dy$ as $U \cdot n \, dS$ seemed to depend on a particular parameterization. (In your formulation, $S$ is the region in the parameter space, right?) However, in writing $$\int_S U\cdot n \, dS$$ no reference is made to a particular parameterization. (Perhaps because any parameterization yields the same result?)

Comment: Wait, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: OK, that clarifies somewhat. I still have the question: does $dS= dudv$? How is Wikipedia speaking of $dS$ without reference to a particular parameterization?

Comment: $\vec n\,dS$ is the quantity defined above. $dS$, since $n$ is a unit vector, is simply the modulus of the quantity above. So not just $du\,dv$, but:
$$ 
\bigg|\frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial u} \wedge \frac{\partial\vec x}{\partial v}\bigg|\,du\,dv.
$$

If it just were $du\,dv$, it would not depend on the embedding $\vec x(u,v)$, that would be strange.

Comment: The vector product above is normal in its direction, because it's the vector product of two tangent vectors.

Comment: Oh, OK. One has to view $\vec{n} dS$ as a pair? That would make sense

Comment: Yes, since it is an area element, which is somewhat "double". In differential forms language, it is a 2-form.